# Precompiling Nunjucks templates with jinja2 compatibility mode

Tags: javascript, node.js, jinja2, nunjucks

Nunjucks has more and more powerful [jinja compatibility mode](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#installjinjacompat). If I include full nunjucks I can use it calling `nunjucks.installJinjaCompat()` before rendering templates (see snippet below):

```js
nunjucks.installJinjaCompat();
var res = nunjucks.renderString(
  '{% for i in list[0:2] %}' +
  '  count: {{ i }}' +
  '{% endfor %}',
  {list: [1, 2, 3, 4]}
);
document.write(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nunjucks/3.0.1/nunjucks.min.js"></script>
```

I cannot figure out how to precompile the same code though. Having file `list.njk`:

```
{% for i in list[0:2] %}
    count: {{ i }}
{% endfor %}
```

I [precompile](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/api.html#precompiling) using default `nunjucks-precompile list.njk > list.js` command, but it raises:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nunjucks/src/precompile.js:130
        throw lib.prettifyError(name, false, err);
        ^

Template render error: (list.njk) [Line 1, Column 15]
  parseAggregate: expected comma after expression
    at Object.exports.prettifyError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:34:15)
    at _precompile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nunjucks/src/precompile.js:130:19)
    at precompile (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nunjucks/src/precompile.js:79:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nunjucks/bin/precompile:62:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
```

error if I use array splicing which is jinja-compatibility specific construct. It compiles if I remove `[0:2]`.

How can I precompile templates taking adventage of jinja compat mode?

I have already tried finding this in documentation, nunjucks issues and checking `nunjucks-precompile` node script for `nunjucks` variable so I could monkeypatch it including `nunjucks.installJinjaCompat()` call; sadly it is not there, it only uses `Environment`.

Comment: Check your installed nunjucks version. I think that you must update it. `Slice` was added 2 april 2017.

Comment: Thanks!, I know that it's a new feature and tried to update using npm to 3.0.1. How can I make sure that I use the newest version? (nunjucks-precompile has no --version switch).

Comment: `npm view nunjucks version` is must be equal to `3.0.1`. Simply I read `nunjucks/src/jinja-compat.js` and found that older version don't have `slice` in code.

Comment: `npm view nunjucks version` returns `3.0.1`. Does the minimal example I provided work for you?

Comment: That is worked example `var nunjucks  = require('nunjucks');
nunjucks.installJinjaCompat();
var env = nunjucks.configure();
console.log(nunjucks.renderString('{% for i in list[0:2] %} count: {{ i }}{% endfor %}', {list: [1, 2, 3, 4]}));` (nunjucks 3.0.1, node 5.11.1, Win7x32)

Comment: Great! Although it does not answer my question. I need to precompile my templates. I already know that rendering strings works and explained it in my question.

Comment: Also, if possible, I would avoid including custom node scripts directly into my stack, as this introduces another framework I need to care about. Right now nunjucks is just a great tool which works out-of-box with standard bash/shell scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `nunjucks-precompile` doesn't have a switch available for `nunjucks.installJinjaCompat()` but you can add it very easily:

Copy the existing CLI file and modify it to correct the require source and install the compat layer:

```
cp node_modules/.bin/nunjucks-precompile .
<edit nunjucks-precompile>
./nunjucks-precompile list.njk
...
```

with nunjucks `3.0.1` `./nunjucks-precompile` should look like

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var path = require('path');
var precompile = require('nunjucks/src/precompile').precompile;
var Environment = require('nunjucks/src/environment').Environment;
var lib = require('nunjucks/src/lib');
var nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
nunjucks.installJinjaCompat();
...
```

Or you can download it from [here](https://gist.github.com/samuelcolvin/33eac9608844a5647032fc5f50633d06).

Comment: Thank you, your solution appears to compile code correctly. I cannot say if it works fully, as I encountered [another problem with setting nunjucks-slim with JinjaCompat mode](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/issues/1019) so I cannot test it yet.